# URDF Links and Joints Orientation

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a URDF file for my six axis robot manipulator. I can launch it to visualize it in rviz via a launch file.

Here is how it looks in rviz : [image: image description]

When I try to move the manipulator using the Joint State Publisher, only the first joint moves at the origin along it's axis. The other links deviate from the origin. It looks like this : [image: image description]

My URDF file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<robot name="Mitsubishi_rv-6sd">

<!-- ...................Material Definitions............................................ -->

<material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
</material>

<material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
</material>

<material name="red">
    <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="green">
    <color rgba="0 1 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="yellow">
    <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
</material>


<!---............................. Link Definitions ................................-->

<link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body0.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="red"/>
    </visual>
</link>


<link name="body1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body1.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="yellow"/>
    </visual>
</link>


<link name="body2">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body2.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="green"/>
    </visual>
</link>


<link name="body3">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body3.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="blue"/>
    </visual>
</link>


<link name="body4">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body4.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="red"/>
    </visual>
</link>


<link name="body5">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://demo/meshes/Final/body5.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name ="green"/>
    </visual>
</link>

  
<!--...........................Joint Definitions.....................................-->

<joint name="j1" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="body1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.96" upper="2.96" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>


<joint name="j2" type="revolute">
    <parent link="body1"/>
    <child link="body2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.96" upper="2.96" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>


<joint name="j3" type="revolute">
    <parent link="body2"/>
    <child link="body3"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.96" upper="2.96" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>


<joint name="j4" type="revolute">
    <parent link="body3"/>
    <child link="body4"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.96" upper="2.96" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>


<joint name="j5" type="revolute">
    <parent link="body4"/>
    <child link="body5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-2.96" upper="2.96" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>

  
</robot>
```

What could be the reason that only one joint is rotating at the axis while the others are deviating?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239841/urdf-links-and-joints-orientation/) by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the geometric origin of each of the links. You will need to change their visual origins such that the actual origin is at the axis of rotation.

Try turning on TF for a better visualization.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-07-20**:
The geometric origin of each of the link is at the base of the robot arm. I have tried to change the visual origins accordingly but that has resulted in a few links hanging in free space.

How can I turn TF on? In Rviz, the TF display is checked already.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-07-20**:
If you turn the robot model display off can you see the tf frames? It could just be that the model is blocking the frames. If so, you could try modifying the alpha of your robot model to make it somewhat transparent.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-20**:\

> In Rviz, the TF display is checked already.

Looking at your rviz screenshot, I think the grey square underneath your robot is actually the Grid display. That is normally much larger than any robot model. ROS uses meters; are you sure your model is correctly scaled @bhavyadoshi26?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-07-21**:
You can also change the marker scale of TF so you can actually see the frames.

**Comment by [ahariharan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27119/ahariharan/) on 2017-08-07**:
I'm having the same issue - what is the recommended way to fix this ? The robot appears to be gigantic in Rviz and the TFs seem to be all bunched together near the origin.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-08**:
The problem is one of scale. As I wrote above: ROS uses meters for everything, and your meshes are most likely using millimeters for units. Scale them down to 1/1000th of their current size, or use the `scale` attribute on the `mesh` tag.